# Clone using ssh from gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab

I have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS(kops).I have nginx running as a loadbalancer in it,i have gitlab running as a node port in the cluster and gitlab is behind nginx. ( so gitlab is accessible using the nginx loadbalancer url/gitlab).

I have a bastion machine from where i run "git clone using SSH" to clone a repository ,but it fails. The public key was uploaded to the SSH keys section in Gitlab and i have the private key with me.

Eg: git clone git@aa82ee1b284b0464bb1353bd2fbccdd2-1957402345.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:root/automation.git
I have tried a number of ways, including generating the keys again, checking security groups of AWS, but no luck.
so is it even possible to connect to the gitlab service from outside through the nginx load balancer url via ssh- like we have in the command:

```
git@aa82ee1b284b0464bb1353bd2fbccdd2-1957402345.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:root/automation.git
```

Comment: how exactly it fails? what's the error message? What's the config of your service/ingress. Is gitlab accessible from other pod within the cluster?

Comment: yes,so i have another use case, where the flux pod tries to clone a repo from gitlab.Git clone over https using the nginx url works fine,however git clone using ssh isn't working.  `nginx                     LoadBalancer   100.69.214.156   aa82ee1b284b0464bb1353bd2fbccdd2-1957402345.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com   443:31944/TCP,5269:32174/TCP,22:32333/TCP`                                      
`gitlab                    NodePort       100.68.131.43    <none>                                                                       8084:31587/TCP,8085:31067/TCP,222:31231/TCP,8223:32121/TCP`

Comment: And the flux pod log is - _ts=2020-09-24T14:12:47.682626365Z caller=loop.go:101 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: running git command: git [clone --mirror ssh://git@aa82ee1b284b0464bb1353bd2fbccdd2-1957402345.ca-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/gitlab/root/automation.git /tmp/flux-gitclone785912997]: context deadline exceeded"_